# on_command_error repeating message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this event to catch errors

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(msg,error):
    if error.args[0] == 'The check functions for command hi failed.':
        await msg.send("{} **is not an NSFW channel**".format(msg.channel.mention))

@commands.is_nsfw()
@bot.command()
async def hi(msg):
    msg.send("OK")
```

When the event catches the error it keeps on sending the same message twice.
For example it would send **#channel_name is not an NSFW channel**

I'm using the rewrite branch of the discord.py

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]?  If you remove all the other code from your bot, leaving just what you have here, do you still see this behavior?

Comment: I had the `await bot.process_commands(msg)` on my `on_message` listener cog and this was causing it to repeat it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send("**Invalid command. Try using** `help` **to figure out commands!**")
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('**Please pass in all requirements.**')
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("**You dont have all the requirements or permissions for using this command :angry:**")
```

Comment: While this code can solve the problem, explanation of how it works is always giving an extra information. Consider adding an explanation.